# Android make a linearlayout border faded

Tags: android, fade

I simply got this. The shape as below, and i use it in my relativelayout. However I need this faded at the bottom like in the image here.

https://s29.postimg.org/ww2zu1j13/Screen_Shot_2017_02_10_at_3_25_20_PM.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#EF357B" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
 <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: You can try using gradient item in your shape, just define startColor, endColor (transparent) and angle (direction) of your gradient

Comment: like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14345943/1636478 just add angle